# Blender doesn't start under Windows 10 version 1703

Tags: windows, audio, error

I have a problem with blender startup, when I start it from Steam it gives me an error with the Audio Board.

I have set board to 16bit when I start the error is gone, but Blender crashes instead. Maybe it's a system problem?

If it is, can you update please? I've already tried with older versions but the problem persists.

Comment: Try using compatibility mode for windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to activate audio mixing in the audio panel of the system, right click and show hidden devices then right click on audio mixing and activate.. try this :D